# Dealer exposed three cards at the turn instead of one

Tags: texas-hold-em

Player 1 bets.  Player 2 calls.  All other players fold.  Dealer burns 1 card and then deals the flop.  Player 1 checks.  Player 2 goes all in. Player 1 calls.  Dealer burns 1 card and then in error, turns up 3 cards instead of 1.  Since the betting is technically complete with one player all in and the other player calling, what is the correct procedure for resolving the prematurely exposed burn card and river card?

Comment: If it's a home game, then you can devise a fair procedure.  For a card room, each card room has its own rules, but in general, they involve a floorperson coming to the table to _randomize_ if the order of the deck cannot be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation as described the error had no consequences.

The players were all in. The dealer should have dealt  three cards, one face up (turn),  one face down (burn), and one face up (river).  Instead, he dealt three face up.   The middle card is the burn card. Just discard it and keep the turn and the river.

The players shouldn't have seen the burn card, but it didn't make any real difference since there was no more betting.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of those situations where there is no clear procedure, to rectify the problem, if I was the floor making the decision, I would mix up the three miss flopped cards, and have the dealer pick one from the three that would be face down. and have the dealer shuffle the remaining two card into the stub so they were still in play. no action would be reversed. alternatively, I would consider giving all bets back and simply cancelling the hand, the button stays to be moved after the hand.